# Finding the parity-check matrix of a generator matrix in $\Bbb F_3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, coding-theory

I am currently looking into linear codes and thought I had understood building a parity-check matrix for a given generator matrix - but the presented solution is anything but what I have.

> **Given a generator matrix $G= \begin{pmatrix}I_3 \\ A\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\1 & 0 & 1\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix}$**
>
> **for a linear code in $\mathbb{F_3}$,the check matrix is** $$H = (-A^{T(?)}  | I_{n-m}) = (-A | I_{6-3}) =\begin{pmatrix}2&2&0&1&0&0 \\2&0&2&0&1&0\\0&2&2&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

I calculated the check matrix and only got this:

$$H_{wrong?} = \begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&1&0&0 \\1&0&1&0&1&0\\0&1&1&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}.
$$

The right-hand $3\times 3$ square is obviously the identity matrix, the left-hand $3\times 3$ square is my transposed matrix $A$ given from $G$.

**Do I have to do further calculations on $A^T$ because of the linear code being in $\mathbb{F_3}$? Is the actual transposed matrix where I transposed 1's have to be -1's for the check matrix, to which I then add the 3? I am completely lost and just spitballing.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}  1 & 1 & 0 \\1 & 0 & 1\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow A^T=\begin{pmatrix}  1 & 1 & 0 \\1 & 0 & 1\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow-A^T=\begin{pmatrix}  -1 & -1 & 0 \\-1 & 0 & -1\\0&-1&-1\end{pmatrix}.$$ Then, since $-1\equiv 2\bmod 3$; we conclude $$-A^T=\begin{pmatrix}  2 & 2 & 0 \\2 & 0 & 2\\0&2&2\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: I will ask a stupid question, to understand this completely - I do understand what you wrote, especially since I pointed it out myself (albeit my approach in the end was wrong).

What I struggle with is the $-1 = 2 mod 3$ and how I can just "use" it like that. The $-1$ is given through my $-A^T$ and the 3 is given because of it being in $\mathbb{F_3}$. Where does the 2 come from?

Comment: Roughly speaking, we have that $\Bbb F_3$ is the ring of integers modulo $3$; consisting of residue classes $\{0,1,2\}$. Anytime we get a number that isn't in this set - we add $3$ an appropriate number of times to get into that set. For a more formal understanding of this - have a read of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, you couldn't have said it clearer.

Comment: No problem. As always - the pleasure, the privilege is mine.